# Is this notch in a stud acceptable?

Tags: walls, kitchens, studs

My contractor notched a wall stud to turn the elbow of the gas line and i don't think he reinforced it.

The wall above it holds a 21 inch wide by 36 inch height wall cabinet. There is also an over the range microwave that is partly supported by that stud. Is this fine?

Did he cut into it too much?

[image]

Comment: IDK, but what's really wrong here is the lack of a cripple on that opening.

Comment: Having a gas line come out of the wall at an *angle* screams wrongness!  I would have him replace it all and do it right.  I would also replace all of that drywall.  This is insane.

Comment: ... and the valve you're about to bury (not the one with the yellow handle... look again)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is a king stud and there is no jack stud for the opening.

> Did he cut into it too much?

It appears that the notch is less than(?), not more than, 50% of the stud width, which is not ideal but it should be ok.

Cabinets and microwave are safe. Is the wall supporting any roofing structure or second story structure? **I.E.** A load bearing wall?

I would have done it differently but it is done now.

Shorter nipple off of the 90 degree elbow, pass the pipe through the stud by drilling a hole in the stud and turning it so it comes straight out of the wall and then a valve. It would have been more PIPE work but in my opinion the correct way to do it.

Comment: Doing it right would have been less work. How the heck are you supposed to drywall that mess?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus -yes.  I meant more pipe work.